# Dealing with a hole (or inner ring) at the intersection of two MultiPolygon polygons in Python Shapely

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, union

I have a problem with Shapely geometry object MultiPolygon (the exact data is shown below) in Python. I need to find a way to merge the small grid cell polygon with the larger polygon but after countless tries.

This is my data:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lpolycoords = [(387250.0, 6671750.0), (387250.0, 6671500.0),(387000.0, 6671500.0),(386750.0, 6671500.0),(386750.0, 6671250.0),(386500.0, 6671250.0),(386500.0, 6671000.0),(386500.0, 6670750.0),(386500.0, 6670500.0),(386250.0, 6670500.0),(386000.0, 6670500.0),(386000.0, 6670250.0),(385750.0, 6670250.0),(385750.0, 6670500.0),(385500.0, 6670500.0),(385250.0, 6670500.0),(385000.0, 6670500.0),(385000.0, 6670750.0),(385000.0, 6671000.0),(384750.0, 6671000.0),(384750.0, 6670750.0),(384750.0, 6670500.0),(384500.0, 6670500.0),(384250.0, 6670500.0),(384250.0, 6670750.0),(384000.0, 6670750.0),(384000.0, 6671000.0),(383750.0, 6671000.0),(383500.0, 6671000.0),(383500.0, 6671250.0),(383500.0, 6671500.0), (383500.0,6671750.0),(383250.0, 6671750.0),(383250.0, 6672000.0),(383500.0, 6672000.0),(383750.0, 6672000.0),(383750.0, 6671750.0),(384000.0, 6671750.0),(384250.0, 6671750.0),(384250.0, 6671500.0),(384500.0, 6671500.0),(384500.0, 6671750.0),(384500.0, 6672000.0),(384500.0, 6672250.0),(384250.0, 6672250.0),(384250.0, 6672500.0),(384250.0, 6672750.0),(384250.0, 6673000.0),(384500.0, 6673000.0),(384500.0, 6673250.0),(384500.0, 6673500.0),(384250.0, 6673500.0),(384250.0, 6673750.0),(384000.0, 6673750.0),(384000.0, 6674000.0),(383750.0, 6674000.0),(383750.0, 6674250.0),(383500.0, 6674250.0),(383500.0, 6674500.0),(383500.0, 6674750.0),(383750.0, 6674750.0),(384000.0, 6674750.0),(384250.0, 6674750.0),(384250.0, 6675000.0),(384500.0, 6675000.0),(384500.0, 6674750.0),(384750.0, 6674750.0),(384750.0, 6675000.0),(384750.0, 6675250.0),(384750.0, 6675500.0),(384750.0, 6675750.0),(385000.0, 6675750.0),(385250.0, 6675750.0),(385500.0, 6675750.0),(385750.0, 6675750.0),(386000.0, 6675750.0),(386000.0, 6675500.0),(386250.0, 6675500.0),(386500.0, 6675500.0),(386500.0, 6675250.0),(386750.0, 6675250.0),(387000.0, 6675250.0),(387250.0, 6675250.0),(387500.0, 6675250.0),(387500.0, 6675000.0),(387500.0, 6674750.0),(387750.0, 6674750.0),(388000.0, 6674750.0),(388000.0, 6674500.0),(388000.0, 6674250.0),(388250.0, 6674250.0),(388250.0, 6674000.0),(388000.0, 6674000.0),(387750.0, 6674000.0),(387750.0, 6673750.0),(387500.0, 6673750.0),(387500.0, 6673500.0),(387250.0, 6673500.0),(387000.0, 6673500.0),(387000.0, 6673250.0),(387000.0, 6673000.0),(387000.0, 6672750.0),(387000.0, 6672500.0),(387000.0, 6672250.0),(387000.0, 6672000.0),(387250.0, 6672000.0),(387250.0, 6671750.0)]
spolycoords = [(385000.0, 6670500.0), (385000.0, 6670250.0), (384750.0, 6670250.0), (384750.0, 6670500.0), (385000.0, 6670500.0)]

largepoly = Polygon(lpolycoords)
smallpoly = Polygon(spolycoords)

# this is the MultiPolygon I am working with
polyUnion = largepoly.union(smallpoly)
```

Let's see how the MultiPolygon `polyUnion` looks like:

[image: My MultiPolygon]

We have a large Polygon representing all the grid cells except for one, and in the bottom of the MultiPolygon, we have the additional one cell Polygon. A hole is created with two vertices of `largepoly` and `smallpoly` being equal. We can verify this like so:

```
set(lpolycoords) & set(spolycoords)
Out[131]: {(384750.0, 6670500.0), (385000.0, 6670500.0)}
```

My question is:

- Is it possible to get exterior coordinates for MultiPolygon
  `unionPoly` in the way that `smallpoly` determines the exterior
  boundary? Inversely, is there a way to get the coordinates of the hole 
  present in `unionPoly`?

Comment: Your geometry must be presented as a multipolygon because a hole can touch the outer ring at zero or one point. Your questions 2) and 3) are interesting but I can't answer them.

Comment: Even though you've been here in GIS SE  a little while, you still haven't taken the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Since the geometry is a *multipolygon* there is no hole, just two points of intersection between the parts. You can detect the locations where the parts touch, and you can construct a polygon which slightly exceeds the MBR, from which you can subtract the shape, which will capture both holes and multipart inclusions as parts. If you focus this Question on your third question, it will answer the second, and effectively, the first.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and apologies for being ignorant on good practices here in GIS SE. Let me focus my question.